# Vim: How to split command line arguments?

Tags: vim

According to the `f-args` documentation, the command line arguments passed to a user defined function, will be automatically split at white-space or tabs as the help shows:

```
                                    *<f-args>*
To allow commands to pass their arguments on to a user-defined function, there
is a special form <f-args> ("function args").  This splits the command
arguments at spaces and tabs, quotes each argument individually, and the
<f-args> sequence is replaced by the comma-separated list of quoted arguments.
See the Mycmd example below.  If no arguments are given <f-args> is removed.
   To embed whitespace into an argument of <f-args>, prepend a backslash.
<f-args> replaces every pair of backslashes (\\) with one backslash.  A
backslash followed by a character other than white space or a backslash
remains unmodified.  Overview:

    command        <f-args> ~
    XX ab          'ab'
    XX a\b         'a\b'
    XX a\ b        'a b'
    XX a\  b       'a ', 'b'
    XX a\\b        'a\b'
    ....
```

However the most basic example does not work:

```
function! TestFunc(...)
  echo a:0
  echo a:000
endfunction

command! -nargs=? TestFunc call TestFunc(<f-args>)

-------------------------------------------------

>  :TestFunc foo bar bla bla, fooo
>  1
>  ['foo bar bla bla, fooo']

>  :TestFunc foo\ bar
>  1
>  ['foo\ bar']
```

I have a bunch of arguments split by whitespaces but vim sees it as one. Why does that happen?

Side question ( can it be somehow configured to actually split arguments at comma? )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specified `-nargs=?`.

The documentation says:

> `-nargs=?`    0 or 1 arguments are allowed
>
> `-nargs=1`    Exactly one argument is required, it includes spaces

and

> Arguments are considered to be separated by (unescaped) spaces or tabs in this
>   context, **except when there is one argument, then the white space is part of
>   the argument**.

(Emphasis mine.)

If you use `-nargs=*` instead, you get the normal behavior.